# ensuring order for css and js files using wp_enqueue_script

Tags: php, wordpress

I have several .css files and .js files that I am enqueuing  through `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` respectively. When I include these files using `<script src="` , the site loads expectedly. But when I use `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` from functions.php , website doesn't work as expected.

I think  the issue might be the order of files in which they are enqueued. When I am enqueueing using `wp_enqueue_script` , I tried to mention the files in the same order as when I am enqueueing using `src` tags but the order is not preserved (as per network tab) .

Using `wp_enqueue_script` , how do I ensure that files are loaded in same order as when using `src` tags ?

```
function travel_register_styles(){

wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min.css', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
...
...
}

function travel_register_scripts() {

    // Enqueue your JavaScript files here
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-ui.js', array(), '1.0', false);
 ...
 ...
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'travel_register_styles');
add_action( 'wp_head', 'travel_register_styles');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'travel_register_scripts');
add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'travel_register_scripts' );
```

Comment: Hi, the 3ird parameters of the wp_enqueue_script() function allow you to define dependencies.
Dependencies will be loaded by wordpress prior to the scripts that depend on it.

So it should help you achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$deps` parameter of `wp_enqueue_script()` to specify dependencies for the script.

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', ... );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-jquery-script', ..., array( 'jquery' ) );
```

See WordPress official documentation:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: There are too many css and js  files and I may not know all the dependencies . I just want them to be inserted in a specific order , which is the order when they are inserted via `src` tags . I know that order works . Is there a way to mention like 1,2,3 .. and so on

Comment: The only reason that scripts would not be printed in the order they were enqueued is because of dependencies, so if you're having that issue, then setting the dependencies is how to fix. I've never seen CSS and JS files be dependent on each other... if that's what you're thinking is the problem, probably not: JS files can definitely be dependent on each other.

Comment: I am not saying css and js are interdependent. All I would like is to enqueue css files in some order and enqueue js files in some order separately without having to know dependencies . Because I know an order that works.  So I would like to first at least make sure that they are inserted in specific order before going to the route of dependencies . Is there a way ?

Comment: Yes: see my answer and previous comment.

Comment: For my question your answer is good. I marked it as answer. But somehow it did not solve my overall problem. Using your method,  I am enqueueing exactly in the same order as when I enqueue using `src` tags but still the page behaves expectedly only when using `src` and not when enqueueing using above method.  Any clue ?

Comment: If you add the output with `<script>` tags, the output with `wp_enqueue_script()`, and the block of `wp_enqueue_script()` calls, may be able to help more specifically. Please post as a new question.

Comment: I opened a new question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76524360/wordpress-wp-enqueue-script-vs-scr-tag-enqueueing