# wordpress - wp_enqueue_script vs scr tag enqueueing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to enqueue scripts using `wp_enqueue_script` but seeing different results than when I am enqueueing scripts using script tags. Result is different in terms of whether a quantity updates or not in UI

using src tag in `front-page.php`, i am enqueuing like this (works. Enqueues and quantity updates correctly)

```
<?php /* Template Name: HomePage */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    ... 
    ...
    <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/daterangepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/jquery.countTo.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/animated-headline.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/jquery.ripples-min.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/quantity-input.js"></script>
        <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/travel/assets/js/main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

using `wp_enqueue_script` (does not work) . It enequeues the file in same order (network tab) as when using `src` tags but quantity does not update when clicking a button

```
        function travel_register_scripts() {
        
          wp_deregister_script('jquery');
           wp_enqueue_script('jquery-3.4.1.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js',array(),'1.0', false);
           wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-ui.js', array('jquery-3.4.1.min'), '1.0', false);
           wp_enqueue_script('popper.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/popper.min.js', array('jquery-ui'), '1.0', false);
             wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('popper.min'), '1.0', false);
           wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-select.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/bootstrap-select.min.js', array('bootstrap.min'), '1.0', false);
           wp_enqueue_script('moment.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/moment.min.js', array('bootstrap-select.min'), '1.0', false);
           wp_enqueue_script('daterangepicker', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/daterangepicker.js', array('moment.min'), '1.0', false);
     wp_enqueue_script('owl.carousel.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array('daterangepicker'), '1.0', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery.fancybox.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js', array('owl.carousel.min'), '1.0', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery.countTo.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.countTo.min.js', array('jquery.fancybox.min'), '1.0', false);
               wp_enqueue_script('animated-headline', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/animated-headline.js', array('jquery.countTo.min'), '1.0', false);
                wp_enqueue_script('jquery.ripples-min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.ripples-min.js', array('animated-headline'), '1.0', false);
                wp_enqueue_script('quantity-input', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/quantity-input.js', array('jquery.ripples-min'), '1.0', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/main.js', array('quantity-input'), '1.0', false);
        
            }
```

And then in the head tag of `front-page.php`

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'travel_register_scripts');
add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'travel_register_scripts' );
```

Why does not it work , when enqueueing using `wp_enqueue_script` ?

Comment: _"It enequeues the file in same order"_ - and in the same place within the document as well?

Comment: In `front-page.php` `src` tags are placed at the very end. I edited above the src part to show that. And while enqueueing using the `wp_enqueue_scripts`, I am using `add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'travel_register_scripts' );`  .  How do I make sure the correct placement of JS when using `wp_enquque_scripts` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to include `true` in the last parameter [(`$in_footer`)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#Parameters) of all the srcipts.

`wp_enqueue_script('jquery-3.4.1.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js',array(),'1.0', true);  ...`

and then include `wp_footer();` just before this tag `</body>` (ending body tag) in `front-page.php`

then we do not need `add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'travel_register_scripts' );`  in `functions.php`

After these changes it correctly enqueues and gives the expected result